# SQL How to total different result sets in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have the below data in one table, what I am trying to do is to calculate how many times each test occurs and the total amount for each test.
I would like the end result to look like this:

```
code = A Quantity = 3 Amount = $15
code = B Quantity = 3 Amount = $21 and so on.
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
A   test    1   $5
A   test    1   $5
A   test    1   $5
B   test1   1   $7
B   test1   1   $7
B   test1   1   $7
C   test2   1   $12
C   test2   1   $12
C   test2   1   $12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate function sum and  group by

```
select  code, sum(quantity), sum(aAmount)
from mytable 
group by code
```